# Control a Command Prompt Window Like a Swing Window using Java

Tags: java, swing, stream, command-prompt, runtime.exec

How would I launch 1 or more Command Prompt windows from a Java application, while still being able to move them around the screen, resize them, show or hide them, and send and receive data / commands?

I am aware of using something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start cmd ; echo hello")`, but that doesn't really have a manipulatable object associated with it, besides the `Process` object, which you can't do much with.

And in terms of input and output, if you create two stream reading objects and connect them to the `Process` object, the Command Prompt window won't show, because you've redirected the standard input / output. I would like some way of sending and receiving data while still having the command prompt visible.

If what I'm asking isn't possible, is there some way to make a swing window look exactly like a Windows Command Prompt window?

Comment: *"..is there some way to make a swing window look exactly like a Windows Command Prompt window?"*  The OS X and Unix/Linux users would curse you, your children and your children's children for attempting to do that.  If this is only for Windows, use .NET (where I'm guessing this is not only possible, but probably also easy), otherwise, just.. ***don't* do that.**